# Camera Module Help

Tags: camera

I have a raspberry pi zero W (2016), and a Arducam 12mp IMX708 Raspi V3 camera module, that I am trying to use as a mini camcorder. So far, I have tried using the libcamera and it connects to the camera, and shows the preview and even records. A couple things are happening though, the framerate never goes above like 15 ish fps even though I have set the resolution to 1080 and fps to 50, which is what the camera is rated for. For now that's what I am trying to achieve. I am fairly new to this sort of thing so any guidance would be appreciated.

Ultimately, I want to be able to have the system setup where a button is pressed that is connected to the GPIO, the camera is set to record following that, and then when the button is pressed again, it will stop, and the file will be saved. But that will take some time to get to.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?